# Is :secure_url necessary in opengraph meta tag if all site resources behind https?

Tags: http, facebook-opengraph, http-status-code-301

My site and all it resourced serving with https, nginx redirect all http request to https.
When using OpenGraph meta, do I need to duplicate all resources with :secure_url?
For example,

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com">
<meta property="og:url:secure_url" content="https://example.com">
```

Or it's enough to specify only one property (but which one - with secure or not) and https resource?

Comment: I'm like to know this too.